# Redundant Condition

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a problem in this block of code that I saw in oracles site.
Can someone explain it for me?

```
Action updateCursorAction = new AbstractAction() {
    boolean shouldDraw = false;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (shouldDraw = !shouldDraw) { // <----- here is my problem, what's this condition for? 
                                       // isn't it always false?
            drawCursor();
        } else {
            eraseCursor();
        }
    }
};

new Timer(300, updateCursorAction).start();
```

Comment: Maybe Oracle posted a bug? (I know...a bug in Oracle's code? Impossible!) What url did you get this from?

Comment: Hehe, I did a double take before I spotted the problem.  Definitely tricky.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (shouldDraw = !shouldDraw)
```

That is not doing `if(shouldDraw != shoundDraw)`.  I think that's what's confusing you.  It is instead doing a negation on `shouldDraw` and checking to see what the result was.

So, the functionality is that if `shouldDraw` was ever `false` going into that condition, it will be set to `true`, and the `if` block will execute.  If `shouldDraw` went into the condition as true, it will get negated, and the else block will be executed.

This will essentially toggle `shouldDraw` between `true` and `false` on every execution of the `ActionListener` which will make the cursor flash.

Comment: Yep, although that shows perfectly the downsides of trying something clever, especially in tutorial codes.

Comment: @Voo, yeah, that should NOT be in a tutorial.

Comment: Suggested improvement: ..., it will get negated, and the else block will be executed.

Comment: +1 another one, for the edit, if only I could. Yes this "style" of code should NEVER be in a tutorial, unless that's what the tutorial is about, and then it should only be there as a demonstration of how to confuse chooks (i.e. Me!).

Comment: @corlettk, I try not to mix opinion and fact in my answers.  It might be unclear to people which are which.  But I do agree whole-heartedly.

Comment: I do both... I just try to be clear and obvious at what is opionion and what is demonstrable, repeatable fact. My opions lean to the verbose, my facts are clean, minimalist, and (hopefully) pithy.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (shouldDraw = !shouldDraw)
```

can be rewritten as

```
shouldDraw = !shouldDraw;
if (shouldDraw)
```

this is a C-style trick where assignment in condition checking can make for more elegant code but it can be confusing to the newer programmer

Answer (score 2):

It's not ACTUALLY a redundant condition, it's just "tricky", "dense", hard to bloody read code!

The tricky bit is that `shouldDraw = !shouldDraw` is what I call a "flip-flop ASSIGNMENT". Each iteration will assign the opposite to it's predecessor, and perform the alternate.

It's ugly! Just grock it, and be glad it's not your code ;-)

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: Hmm, I kinda think it's an elegant solution.  It's not trick to tell what it's doing if you don't mistake it for a `!=` operator.

Comment: Every time you assign a variable inside an if statement, a kitten dies.

Answer (score 1):

basically this piece of code will draw 1 out of 2 times. and it will erase the other 50%

a bit confusing but logical.

Comment: A down vote was not necessary a simple edit would be sufficient.